# Need help to quicken this code in Python 2

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am solving this problem in [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/play-game/submissions/code/10177364).

My code took 0.07s to solve with an input with 1000 length but for an input with 100,000 length this code could not solve it within 10s. I am wondering which steps of my code could be modified to speed up the
execution.

My code is:

```
# Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
def find_payoff(t,m): 
    if m<=3:
        return sum(t)                
    else:
        t1=[sum(t[i:]) for i in range(m)]
        opt_pay=[0]*m
        opt_pay[m-3:m]=[sum(t[m-i:m]) for i in range(3,0,-1)]
        for i in range(m-4,-1,-1):
            opt_pay[i]=max([sum(t[i:i+j+1])+t1[i+j+1]-opt_pay[i+j+1] for j in range(3)])
    return opt_pay[0]


n=input()

for i in range(n):
    m=input()   
    t=map(int, raw_input().split())
    print find_payoff(t,m)
```

Comment: You might want to double check that link, it doesn't appear to lead to anything that makes sense in the context of your question here.

Comment: @TML, if you go to the link, click on `Problem` in the header.

Comment: How long did your code take for 100,000? It sounds like you're looking for part of your algorithm that isn't scaling linearly or better. This is likely in your loop - I'd focus on what it's doing in there.

Comment: Are you sure this code correctly solves the problem? It looks like it is not optimal.

Comment: I am sure this code correctly solves the problem as it was doing for less than 1000 number of variables length. I believe it is also optimal because it is linear with the data size which I was taught as the holy grail of programmer. I just run the code on the website and it says it cannot solve it with in 10 second. I will give more updates once I will run the code on my machine.

Comment: Hi Guys, I finally solved the problem. I was using too much memory space for variables t1 and opt_pay while just needed a list of length 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to solve this problem. I was using too much space for variables `t1` and `opt_pay`. Using my new code, I reduced the length of these variables to 3 and reduced the execution time to 1 second. The final code is here if you are interested.

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
def find_payoff(t,m): 
    if m<=3:
        return sum(t)                
    else:
        t1=[sum(t[m-i:]) for i in range(3,0,-1)]
        opt_pay=t1[:]        
        for i in range(m-4,-1,-1):
            tmp=max([sum(t[i:i+j+1])+t1[j]-opt_pay[j] for j in range(3)])
            opt_pay[0],opt_pay[1:]=tmp,opt_pay[0:2]
            t1[0],t1[1:]=t1[0]+t[i],t1[0:2]          
    return opt_pay[0]


n=input()

for i in range(n):
    m=input()   
    t=map(int, raw_input().split())
    print find_payoff(t,m)
```